# how to limit the maximum number of lines in my Monoco editor to 100？

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to limit the maximum number of lines in monaco-editor to 100. By the way, can I limit the maximum number of words in monaco-editor?

As described above, I have tried the property "lineNumber",it seems like it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there's no property or setting that would limit the acceptable size in the editor, but you could register a change listener and cancel all further input when the content size has reached a certain limit.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!  I'v registered "onDidChangeModelContent" listener, but I don't know how to cancel all further input. I delete the content which out of range, I think it's wrong, here is the code: ``` let colum = this._editor.getModel().getLineMaxColumn(this.maximum);
            let range = new monaco.Range(this.maximum, colum, count+1);
            let content = this._editor.getModel().getValueInRange(range);
            this._editor.executeEdits('log-source', [{ identifier: 'event_id', range: range, text: null, forceMoveMarkers:true }]);```